Changing Conditional format rule seems to work but doesn't in office-js
I am trying to write some simple TypeScript code to change a conditional formatting rule in an Excel file. To repro my issue:

Open a blank Excel file
Enter 1 in A1
Click “Home”, Conditional formatting”, “New Rule”
Choose “Format only cells that contain”
Select “Specific text” in the Format only cells with: drop-down on
the left
Select “Containing” in the second drop-down
Enter 123 in the box.
OK back to Excel.
Open Script lab and import the code below and run it
Click the Run button, the console should state 123, followed by 456.
Click Conditional formatting, Manager Rules.
You should see that the contains text rule is unchanged!

What is wrong with this code?
================Script lab code================
name: CheckCF
description: ''
host: EXCEL
api_set: {}
script:
  content: |
    $("#run").on("click", () => tryCatch(run));

    async function run() {
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

        let cfRules = sheet.getRange("A1").conditionalFormats;
        let cf = cfRules.getItemAt(0);
        let containsTextCF = cf.textComparisonOrNullObject;
        containsTextCF.load();
        await context.sync();
        console.log(containsTextCF.rule.text);
        containsTextCF.rule.text = "456";
        await context.sync();
        console.log(containsTextCF.rule.text);
      });
    }

    /** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
    async function tryCatch(callback) {
      try {
        await callback();
      } catch (error) {
        // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  language: typescript
template:
  content: |
    <button id="run" class="ms-Button">
        <span class="ms-Button-label">Run</span>
    </button>
  language: html
style:
  content: |-
    section.samples {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    section.samples .ms-Button, section.setup .ms-Button {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        min-width: 80px;
    }
  language: css
libraries: |
  https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js
  @types/office-js

  office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.min.css
  office-ui-fabric-js@1.4.0/dist/css/fabric.components.min.css

  core-js@2.4.1/client/core.min.js
  @types/core-js

  jquery@3.1.1
  @types/jquery@3.3.1

================End of Script lab code================

It appears the correct syntax to modify the rule as I intended is this:
containsTextCF.rule = { operator: "Contains", text: "456" };

